# RestEasy accept Java object in input

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, resteasy, wildfly-10

I'm trying to build a REST service in my webapp using Wildfly as Application Server and RestEasy as library for Rest service.
When I call the right url, i receive this exception:

```
22:57:34,099 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:382)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:116)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociati.............
```

The url is this:

http://localhost:8080/rest/email/myName/myEmail/myMessage

My java class implementation:

```
@Path("/email")
public class EmailRestfulImpl 
{

    @POST
    @Path("/{name}/{address}/{message}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendContactUs(EmailRequest emailRequest)
    {
        String result = "emailRequest saved : " + emailRequest.getName();
        return Response.status(201).entity(emailRequest).build();
    }
}
```

My Java object:

```
public class EmailRequest implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String message;

    public EmailRequest() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

My web.xml configuration:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Smoney-RS</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

And finally, my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the screen of the request:
[image]

EDIT 2:
If i add the content-type, it seems works but i receive a java exception!

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you consuming the web service?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin sorry, I've edited my question :)

Comment: How do you *call the right url*?

Comment: What is your request?

Comment: sorry @CássioMazzochiMolin but what do you mean? the correct url is listed in the question and I call the url through POST action, using the tool integrated in Intellij for testing Restful webservices. The tool is called "Test RESTful WebService"

Comment: @ssc I would like accept the java object in input with the fields filled by url parameters...

Comment: What are you using as client? Postman? cURL? A web page? Any other tool?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I'm using a web page. The purpose is call these rest service using angularjs in my web page

Comment: And why don't you show the Angular code in your question? Don't expect us to guess what your client code looks like.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I have not yet implemented the Angular code because i want to test the rest ws before use angularjs. I'm learning how does it works and i'm building some test cases to understand the rest services.

Comment: If you haven't implemented the client yet, how are you performing the request to your service? Could you show what your request looks like?

Comment: @user3449772 Are you sending the Content-Type Header as json in your request header?

Comment: You must ensure your request contains the following headers: `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: FWIW those dependencies should be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`. The container already provides them for you.

Comment: If your JSON payload contains `name`, `address` and `message` properties, you won't need the `@Path("/{name}/{address}/{message}")` annotation.

Comment: I have edited my question with some news

Comment: Your request body seems to be empty. How do you want to convert an empty body to your object?

Comment: Yes, i understand this...but how can i map the object as json?? The request is not empty because the url seems correct...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: EmailRequest should map to this 
{  
   "name":"john",
   "address":"john@test.com",
   "message":"hello"
}
try posting that